# Map and Subscribe in the new AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I installed new Version of Angularfire and I like to new how you now access the map and subscribe methods.

```
getEinnahmen(){
this.einnahmen = 0;

this.db.list("/Budget",{query:{
     orderByChild:'ausgabe',
     equalTo: 'Einnahme'
   }}).map(items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.betrag, 0))
   // Log the total
     .subscribe(total => {
       console.log(total);
       this.einnahmen = total + 2500;
     });

    return this.einnahmen;

  }
```

How can i get the sum of the dataentries now, because the system cant find the map or the subscribe method on the FirebaseListObservable.

Comment: Did you import the namespace?
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

This is the basic example to test wheather you are getting the data or not and then try to map it

```
this.AngularFire.database.list("/Budget/")
.map((items) => { //first map
 console.log(items);
 return items.map(item => { //second map
  console.log(items);
  console.log(item);
})
```

})

In the Html you can use async so that you dont have to worry about unsubscribing it. When you use async it will take care of unsubscribing itself.